# Unity: Overwrite APK automatically on Android debug build?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every time I "Build and Run" my project to debug it on my phone it asks me to save the APK and I have to overwrite the existing one.  Is there any way to just output this to a "temp" file and automatically overwrite it?  Visual Studio does this automatically when doing a Windows build.  The .exe is just automatically output to the /build folder with no input.

Comment: A coworker says this does not happen to him; it just builds and runs.  I can't find any settings that would cause this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If the build location is *inside* your project folder, it will prompt you to save and overwrite every time.

---

#### Here is a crappy, 4 minute video demonstrating the behavior:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWS6r6EjduY

---

It turns out that I had initially saved the APK inside the project folder.  This is what caused the anomalous behavior.

Once I saved the APK to another folder, subsequent builds did not prompt me to overwrite the file.

**It is now set to save outside my project folder and it works as expected.**

Comment: I think you should mark your answer as the correct 'answer' to your problem.

Comment: I will after the 2 day wait period.

Comment: This answer is **wrong**. It has nothing to do with placing the file in the Project folder outside the project folder You will **always** get the overwrite window unless you use File--->Build & Run like I said in my answer instead of Build And Run from the Build Settings. I've been using Unity with my APK or exe output in my Project folder. It does not prompt me every time when I use the solution in my answer. I am sure most people can confirm this.If you are getting something else, you need to reinstall Unity or file for a bug report. I just tried this again and what you said is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm sorry you're upset, but it's the way it works. I validated twice.

Comment: Although there is no documentation about the expected behavior we would expect some consistency. As Programmer suggested maybe you can file a bug report.

Comment: I know from personal experience, that the previous versions of Unity behaved as Programmer indicated.  However, since updating, this is no longer the case.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Unity 2021.3.14f1

Answer (score 2):

The described problem in your question only happens when you click the **Build and Run** button from the **Player Settings**.

After you click the **Build and Run** button from the **Player Settings** once, close the **Player Settings**.

You can now build your project without any popup window that ask you about overwriting your old file by going to  **File**--->**Build & Run** each time you want to build and run your project.

Comment: That may be the intended behavior, but I assure you it is not the behavior I am experiencing.  I am using CTRL+B.  The Build Settings dialog is not open.

Comment: How about don't use a short-cut for now until you get what I have in my answer working. When the windows pop-up from "File--->Build & Run", chose your directory to save the file. Then click Save and then cancel the build. Unity will auto-store the directory. Now, you can go to File--->Build & Run. Try that!

Comment: This did not fix it for me. However, the accepted answer did.

Comment: Used to work, doesn't in Unity 2021.3.14f1

Answer (score 1):

I use an editor script to automate builds for different platforms. This skips confirmation any prompts, and allows you to set up different build modes easily. Here's an example of what a simple build script would look like for your use case:
(This script must be placed in `Assets/Editor`)

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

public class BuildSettings
{
    [MenuItem("Build/Android %#&B")]
    public static void BuildForAndroid()
    {
        EditorSceneManager.SaveScene(EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene());
        BuildPlayerOptions options = new();
        options.locationPathName = @"C:\Users\USERNAME\Unity\PROJECTNAME\Builds\AndroidBuild\ProjectName.apk";
        options.scenes = new string[] { @"Assets\Scenes\Scene1", @"Assets\Scenes\Scene2" };
        options.options = BuildOptions.AutoRunPlayer;
        options.target = BuildTarget.Android;
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(options);
    }
}
```

The "`%#&B`" in the `MenuItem` line specifies a keyboard shortcut, in this case, Ctrl + Shift + Alt + B

Relevant documentation :
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html